# Can we make performance-based library recommendations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28201717/541686) was downvoted through the floor and closed because questions that ask for library recommendations are "off-topic", apparently.

This is absolutely ludicrous.

#### There is nothing about performance that would attract "opinions" any more than any other kind of question would.

*[There](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7652505/541686) [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9447193/541686) [**tons**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3692602/541686) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/873976/541686) [great](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3291895/541686), [popular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9047391/541686) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6271791/541686) [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11552073/541686) [for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8002560/541686) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/q/124239/541686) ["fastest"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3167024/541686) [library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25665744/541686) [for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13488802/541686) [various](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1981069/541686) [tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5205641/541686).*

Can we make them on-topic so people can stop knee-jerk downvoting and closing these questions?
It's plainly ridiculous and it makes the site worse, not better.

Comment: Those questions (that you linked) have attracted opinion-based answers. If you look at them, you'll see people just recommending their favorite library.

Comment: Well, first a comment about your specific question: You are a bit vague about what syntax and features are neccessary. I mean, I can easily write a super-fast regex-machine, which knows just one pattern, matching everything/nothing.

Comment: The problem with 'what's the fastest X' is that no answers ever show why something is the fastest; it ends up being either just a "list of libraries I like" or "this one is the fastest because I said so."  If these answers had benchmarks it'd be a different story.

Comment: Now, to your examples: Most are old or ancient, though there was one from 2014 too. Nearly all answers are just a link (plus sometimes a laudatio, without anything concrete), so low-quality. Also, they might have slipped through the cracks till now, but your highlighting those broken windows drew a moderator to do what should have happened.

Comment: If you ask for performance, you should ask along the lines of "*What techniques are employed to make task XY super-fast, and for what kind of inputs to XY do they work?*" This will probably be a bit broad, but *if* someone cares to write a good answer it will actually be helpful. And will certainly attract comments/references like "*…as was implemented in library YZ*".

Comment: @remyabel: If I see a library has good performance, heck yeah it's going to become my favorite library and I'm going to recommend it, because it will serve the needs of others too. What's wrong with that? That seems like the perfect kind of answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator: There's nothing vague about my question, a regex machine that knows just one pattern is not a regex machine.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: But who cares *why* it's fastest? When you're looking for the fastest FFT library do you really care *why* it's fastest? It's fastest when it returns the results for the majority of cases faster than other libraries. Often such a thing exists, sometimes it doesn't. Anyhow, with the currently policy, **people don't even have a *chance* to show benchmark results in the first place** because the question is closed before they can ever answer it, so your reason about that being a "different story" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Deduplicator: You can't be serious telling me that questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/874051/541686) are low-quality, can you? The question *and* the answer look high-quality to me, **and the OP accepted the answer**, meaning the answer was obviously helpful. What exactly is low quality here?

Comment: @Bergi: I (and most people) typically really don't care *why* a library is fast though -- if I wanted to write it myself then I wouldn't be looking for a library in the first place.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: It's off topic and downvoted... move along...

Answer (score 7):

Your question is asking for a library recommendation, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow through and through. Although you argue that "speed is a very concrete thing", that statistic is meaningless without further elaboration. Different libraries claim to be faster at different things based on different metrics, on one particular operating system, on one particular set of hardware. The question requires more detail than just "what's the fastest library?"

Secondly, the questions you linked are not very good examples. The answers in those questions are crap, primarily link-only answers and there isn't any clear consensus on what the "fastest" library is. People just end up recommending their favorite library. The fact that they haven't been closed isn't proof of anything, as plenty of crap questions escape closure either because policies have changed since then or nobody bothered to close them (they now have been by a moderator.) You ask how your question can attract opinion-based or spam answers... you gave perfect examples.

Comment: Any statistic is meaningless without enough elaboration.  While this question may have a specific answer in the specific case (I can write a real-nice ".*" regex parser)  there may also be a good general case answer.  As a hard and fast rule, asking for the fastest = bad question is an OK heuristic.  However, in this case it seems reasonable.  He clearly has a distinct real world problem with many (opinionated) solutions, but that doesn't mean its off topic because all questions are opinionated.

Comment: Link-only answers? Favorite books? Opinion-based answer? Have you never looked at [*"The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/541686)??? That seems to contain a horrible combination of those criteria. If those criteria are really so bad then why isn't it deleted? Admit it: just because it's subjective and has 1-2 lines of text per link doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Comment: @Mehrdad: that question you link to is an exception that's been discussed on meta. It stays in that state because the answer is actually maintained (look at the revision history). Most other recommendation questions are left there to rot and end up being less accurate than a plain google search.

Comment: @Mat: I don't get it, is the problem the subjectivity or link-only-ness or favorite-ness of the answers, or is it the fact that they might become outdated? Heck, is the problem with the question or the answer? You're using the justification for one problem as the justification for something else.

Comment: @Mehrdad: the problem is the combination of all that, and stems from the type of question. Recommendation questions lead to opinion-based, low-quality (down to spam), quick to obsolete answers.

Comment: Meta FAQ: [Why is "The Definitive C++ Book List" question allowed but other book recommendation question are not?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144359), @Mehrdad