# Update popular closed library recommendation answers (Java bean mapping)

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, recommendation-questions

The Java ecosystem has plenty of projects for mapping beans. They are difficult to compare. Google searches for "java bean mappers" reliably return this question on the first result page, which has a kind of overview in the second answer:

[any tool for java object to object mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764)

That answer has several duplicates as listed below. The accepted answer is not the highest-voted. The information given in all highest-voted answers is decaying.

Assuming that having an off-topic question with up-to-date answers is better than having that same off-topic questions with decayed answers, what should editors do?

- No special action, look the other way, "no harm done"
- Move/copy the question to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com (but will search engines follow?)
- Repair the question [any tool for java object to object mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764) ? by asking: "How can I map objects in Java?", then ask to reopen
- Keep improving the highest-voted answer (edit war)?
- Keep improving the accepted answer (edit war)?

Likely duplicates of the top answer on Google:

- *[Alternative to dozer for bean mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800743/alternative-to-dozer-for-bean-mapping)*
- *[Java bean mapping library - which to choose (transforming one object to another)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796470/java-bean-mapping-library-which-to-choose-transforming-one-object-to-another)*
- *[Java Mapping tool (bean to bean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591011/java-mapping-tool-bean-to-bean)*
- *[Object mapper for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313128/object-mapper-for-java)*
- *[Java mapping: Selma vs MapStruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786737/java-mapping-selma-vs-mapstruct)*
- *[BO <=> DTO mapper in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523601/bo-dto-mapper-in-java)*
- *[How to map a DTO to an existing JPA entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536060/how-to-map-a-dto-to-an-existing-jpa-entity)*
- *[How to map persistent objects to DTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650616/how-to-map-persistent-objects-to-dto)*
- *[DTO and mapper generation from Domain Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828403/dto-and-mapper-generation-from-domain-objects)*
- *[DTO pattern: Best way to copy properties between two objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117403/dto-pattern-best-way-to-copy-properties-between-two-objects)*

Similar meta-questions:

- *[Allow software tool recommendations for niche purposes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294130/allow-software-tool-recommendations-for-niche-purposes)*
- *[What's the difference between "How can I do X?" and "What library does X?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256226/whats-the-difference-between-how-can-i-do-x-and-what-library-does-x)*
- *[Can we make performance-based library recommendations on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284818/can-we-make-performance-based-library-recommendations-on-topic)*
- *[Let's rescue wayward resource requests! (trial run)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341987/lets-rescue-wayward-resource-requests-trial-run)*

Comment: related? [Let's rescue wayward resource requests! (trial run)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987/839601)

Comment: @gnat thx. I think that one is about reopening questions which can be changed to non-recommendation-questions.