# What kind of questions can separate an opinion based question from an acceptable question?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

I want to gather more information about [Jekyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jekyll_(software)) as a substitute for [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_%28JavaScript_library%29) front end in my web application. Asking just this would result in the question being opinion-based.

However, the only other way for me to gather such information will be to research about the two and implement both systems to actually gain some information, which is not a very efficient way given the large programmer community available on Stack Overflow.

So, are there a few guidelines that can help convert an opinion based question of this kind to an acceptable question? For instance - the difference in rendering speed for a large document, customizability of elements, etc.

Comment: This sounds like a combination library recommendation and benchmarking question, both of which are off-topic. See [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284818/can-we-make-performance-based-library-recommendations-on-topic), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185287/why-questions-asking-for-benchmarks-are-considered-non-objective-or-not-constru).

Comment: As far as "to research... and implement... which is not a very efficient way given the large programmer community available on Stack Overflow", I think a lot of people have this exact thought, except applied to any and all programming projects they embark on. A person's productivity needs don't justify asking an off-topic question or not doing their own research. Quite the opposite is true, in fact: given the large programmer community available on Stack Overflow, one needs to do _more work_ to make a question worth everyone's attention and time, not less.

Answer (score 9):

Jeff Atwood, the original founder of Stack Overflow, actually wrote a [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/) on this very subject.

For your case, I'm afraid you're all out of luck, though, as asking for rendering speeds is silly, if you want to know, measure for your specific server and workload, that question is way too broad with too many variables in the mix.

Same goes for customizability.

Comparing frameworks and programming languages is really not something Stack Overflow is about. So, really, you have to research it yourself. And proceed with a healthy amount of scepticism if you do, there are plenty of bad blogs that make weird comparisons and draw unsubstantiated or plain wrong conclusions. We prefer not to have stuff like that on Stack Overflow.

Honestly, imo researching and testing it yourself is not a waste of time. Reading biased opinions of others often is, though.

Comment: I agree with you on everything you say, except what if there is a time crunch/resource crunch present? wouldn't a concise opinion help someone?
Also, as for the speeds, it would require a newbie to learn both the techs, setup and run to find the speed whereas being able to refer to an existing stat would be so much more efficient. 
The reason I ask for such a guideline on stack overflow is because we have been able to eliminate a lot of jargaon in answers. The habit might reflect off on opinoins too - as they might be stat based.

Comment: A concise opinion helps exactly zero. If I'd say _Choose that first thing you named_, you wouldn't be helped at all. Benchmarks are often biased, say framework X caches to disk, while framework Y keeps everything in memory. In a small memory SSD server, framework X would run circles around framework Y, while the opposite would be true for a server with abundant memory and a slow disk. Perhaps one compresses for faster reads, but this increases CPU load, which makes it faster on some machines, and slower on others. Benchmarks are near-meaningless if the machine or task is not representative.

Comment: @fireball.1 *except what if there is a time crunch/resource crunch present?* That's what consultants are for. We have no way of guaranteeing timely support. Urgency does not preclude our process.

Comment: If you're in a time crunch, then [Stack Overflow probably isn't the best place to go anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273153/7496073).